# How to search user details from local Openfire server using aSmack library?

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack

I'm developing chat application, In  which I'm using openfire server and asmack library. I want to search users who was registered on that server.

Here is the code which I have written..

```
    UserSearchManager search = new UserSearchManager(connection);  
            try {
                Log.d("JWP", "cc:"+connection.getServiceName());
                org.jivesoftware.smackx.Form searchForm = search.getSearchForm("search."+connection.getServiceName());
                org.jivesoftware.smackx.Form answerForm = searchForm.createAnswerForm();  
                answerForm.setAnswer("Username", true);  
                answerForm.setAnswer("search", editTextSearch.getText().toString());  
                org.jivesoftware.smackx.ReportedData data;
                data = search.getSearchResults(answerForm,"search."+connection.getServiceName());
                if(data.getRows() != null){   
                    Iterator<org.jivesoftware.smackx.ReportedData.Row> it = data.getRows();
                    while(it.hasNext()){
                        org.jivesoftware.smackx.ReportedData.Row row = it.next();
                        Iterator iterator = row.getValues("jid");
                        if(iterator.hasNext()){
                            String value = iterator.next().toString();
                            Log.i("Iteartor values......"," "+value);
                        }
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(Welcome.this,"Username Exists",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            catch (XMPPException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

But here getSerachFrom() method returns null value, have tried various things but don't understand why this is happening. 
My openfire server having number of registered users.

Comment: is your connection object not null...please check

Comment: Is the search plugin installed on the server?

Comment: @KunalS.Kushwah: I have cheked my XMPPConnection object is not null..

Comment: @Robin: have checked, search plugins are installed on my openfire server, but still result is null..

Comment: I have found solution myself... just add the code as given here using providerManager instance- pm.addIQProvider("query","jabber:iq:search", new UserSearch.Provider()); all works fine.

Comment: hi @Vikas, did you tried searching users with their display name. I want this implementation. can you guide me on how to achieve this.